# Fix creeky old wooden floor

Tags: wood, flooring, floor, hardwood-floor, noise

The duplex I live in was built around the 1920s and still has the original wood floor but its very creeky and the neighbors downstairs are always complaining so I'd like to fix it.

I'm wondering if there is a way I could pull up some of the wood planks without damaging them so I can fix the problem underneath and put the wood back in place afterwards.  Or if there is a better solution.

Ive tried drilling screw but it hasnt helped.  And i mop the floor with polish every couple of weeks and for about a day the lubrication maxs the creeking lessen but only works for about a day.

My friend told me to try using sand.  He said that if I sweep sand all over the floor it will get into the cracks and act as padding to stop the creeking, but there isn't really much space between each plank so I'm doubtful that much sand will be able to work its way underneath the boards.  I'm going to try it later today though.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you can locate your floor joists, you can use a longer, ~2-2.5" finish nail and nail both finish floor and subfloor to the joist. Once the subfloor is tightened down, you can spot nail the finish floor to the subfloor as needed. I did that in my 1928 house and it worked.

Comment: I have done a lot of that....

Comment: Some people have used talcum powder to lessen a squeaky floor. There are many possible solutions. If you mop it often, then you don't want to add something that will thicken or harden and crumble, and then be hard to remove. Sand being swept into the cracks? I have never heard of that, and I bet it could potentially scratch the surface as you walk on it and sweep it, and over time the sand might come back up and cause more scratching. Using a screw, rather than a nail, will result in a less squeaky floor. There is a kit made just for this.